# how can i get an array of recently inserted records ids?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I have one table named "questions". This table may have multiple questions. Here I am looping over the insert query to insert all question values for having duplicate questions. It is successfully adding questions, but the issue is I can't get the list or array of recently inserted question records ids.

Here is the code.

```
   <cfloop query="questions">
      <cfquery name="insertDuplicatequestions">
          INSERT INTO questions (
              survey_Id, questiontype_Id, question, rank, isrequired
          )
          VALUES 
          (
              <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bigint" value="#getSurveyid.id#">
             , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bigint" value="#questions.questiontype_Id#">
             , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#questions.question#">
             , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#questions.rank#">
             , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#questions.isrequired#"> 
          ) 
          <cfif questions.CurrentRow LT questions.RecordCount>,</cfif>
      </cfquery> 

      <cfquery name="getQuestionid">
       SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id                  
      </cfquery>  
       <cfset response = getQuestionid.id>
  </cfloop>
```

I have tried with LAST_INSERT_ID(), but it retrieves last and single record id. Could anyone please let me know if there is anyway to figure out this. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe add a column for creation date? Then you can select using that date in descending order

Comment: In Ms Sql sever you can use the output clause.

Comment: yeah that's right, but I am using mySql.

Comment: Have you tried using the `result` attribute of `cfquery` and looking at the value of the `generated_key`?

Comment: yeah I heard about generated_key but i never used it now i will give a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(More of an addendum, but it is too long for comments ... )

[Like RandomSeed said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18514752/104223), capturing multiple record id's generated by an `insert` is not supported in MySQL. One of the alternatives he described is inserting the records individually, and capturing the new ID on each iteration. Here is a rough outline of how you might do that using cfquery's [`result`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html) attribute.

```
 <!--- initialize array that will store the new ids --> 
 <cfset idArray = []>

 <!--- use a transaction to ensure ALL of the inserts succeed or fail together -->
 <cftransaction>
     <cfloop ...>

         <!--- use the "result" attribute to capture the new id --->
         <cfquery result="addRecord" ....>
           INSERT INTO YourTable (...) VALUES (...);
         </cfquery>

         <!--- save the id in the array -->
         <cfset arrayAppend(idArray, addRecord.GENERATED_KEY)>

     </cfloop>
 </cftransaction>

 <!--- display new id's --->
 <cfdump var="#idArray#">
```

As an aside, while you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, it should normally be placed inside the same `cfquery` tags as the INSERT to guaranteed you get the last id for the current connection. Note: For it to work, [the datasource settings must allow multiple statements](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/357.cfm) (not enabled by default).

Comment: Thanks a lot.... it works exactly what i want. is there any way to convert idArray into list ? i have tried with ArrayToList but doesn't work.

Comment: ArrayToList is the right function. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? How are you trying to use it in code?

Comment: <cfset questionid = ArrayToList(idArray,",")> in this way i have converted into list it works fine.. I am using this inside another query loop answers.
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true" value="#questionid#">

Comment: That is the right syntax to pass it to the database as a list. Just make sure you are using the `IN` operator. ie   `WHERE ColumnName IN ( <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true" value="#questionid#"> )`

Comment: I am using this list while inserting answers, so I think we can't use  IN clause in insert query ?

Comment: Since this sounds like a different issue, it is probably best to open a new question. Be sure to include the full code and the error message you are getting.

Comment: here is my new question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536222/how-can-i-insert-list-of-ids-while-adding-records

Answer (score 4):

There is no native way to do it. Your best call would be adding a timestamp column to your table, representing the insertion date (by default, a `TIMESTAMP` field takes `NOW()` as a default value).

Alternatively, you could just check the result of each insertion from within your application code (eg. with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`). Then build the array in your application code.

Comment: but here in this case i need list of ids so that i can use it for adding answers.

Comment: Not sure I'm getting you right. `foreach ($questions as $q) { insert($q); $lastId = getLastInsertId(); $idArray[] = $lastId); }`. Why would this not work?

Comment: Ok I understand. My first suggestion is probably not fit to your need. The second alternative should do.

Comment: yeah this make sense to me, but here it gives syntax error I am not sure to use it with Coldfusion.

Comment: I now understand you are building a query which inserts multiple rows at a time (sorry, I am not at all familiar with this syntax). You will need to insert the rows one by one, and call `LAST_INSERT_ID()` at each iteration.

Comment: @MSKhan - Please update your question with your latest attempt and the error. Not sure what your code looks like, but you need to run the cfqueries separately ie *inside* the loop, then save the new ID after each query.

Comment: @Leigh -I have updated the question this is what i have tried but still it is showing only single id though i have 2 questions.

Answer (score 0):

`last_insert_id()` works as it's name: you get the ID of the **LAST** record you inserted. If you're inserting multiple records, then you'll have to do a last_insert_id() for EVERY record. There is no way to retrieve the IDs of the previous inserts - those are lost.