# how can i insert list of ids while adding records?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I have a list of question ids to be inserted into an answers table while adding records.

```
<!--- answers query --->
<cfquery name="answers">
    SELECT answer, rank 
    FROM answers 
    WHERE question_id IN (<cfqueryparam  cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true" separator="," value="#qid#">)                       
</cfquery>
```

the `qid` is the list of old question id through which I am retrieving answers and then I am duplicating the same answers with newer question id.

```
<!--- list of questionids --->
<cfset questionid = ArrayToList(idArray)> 
    <cfquery name="insertanswers">
        INSERT INTO answers (
            question_id, answer, rank
        )
        VALUES 
            <cfloop query="answers">
                (
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true" separator="," value="#questionid#">
                ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#answers.answer#">
                ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#answers.rank#">
                )
                <cfif answers.CurrentRow LT answers.RecordCount>,</cfif> 
            </cfloop>
    </cfquery>
```

While adding records I am getting `column count doesn't match value count` error but when I wrap code with `cftry` and dump it I found that it is getting two ids for each answer in form of comma delimited. Is there any way to pass only single id for each answer? I am just replacing the older question ids with newer one.

Comment: Yeah, you cannot use <cfqueryparam list="true"...> this way. What does the "answers" query look like? (I do not see the "old" question id anywhere).

Comment: I have updated the question. here I am just duplicating existing records this is the part of app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to link the old and new id's, you will need a different approach than [the one used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18520029/104223). When you generate the new question records, store the id's in a structure, rather than an array, so you can maintain a mapping of old => new values.

```
<!--- initialize mapping of old => new ids --> 
 <cfset idMapping = {}>

  <cfloop ...>

         <!--- use the "result" attribute to capture the new id --->
         <cfquery result="addRecord" ....>
           INSERT INTO YourTable (...) VALUES (...);
         </cfquery>

         <!--- save the id in the array -->
         <cfset idMapping[ oldQuestionID ] = addRecord.GENERATED_KEY>

 </cfloop>
```

When you insert the new answers, use the old id to do a look up and grab the new question id from the structure. This needs validation, but here is the general idea.

*Note: To ensure data integrity, both query blocks should be enclosed in a single `<cftransaction>`*

```
   <cfquery name="insertanswers">
        INSERT INTO answers (
            question_id, answer, rank
        )
        VALUES 
            <cfloop query="answers">
                (
                <!--- get the new id from the structure --->
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#idMapping[ oldQuestionID ]#">
                ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#answers.answer#">
                ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#answers.rank#">
                )
                <cfif answers.CurrentRow LT answers.RecordCount>,</cfif> 
            </cfloop>
    </cfquery>
```

**Update 1:**

Here is a complete example:

- [SQL](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6392247#file-gistfile1-sql)
- [CF Code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6392229#file-gistfile1-cfm)

**Update 2:**

If this is a regular occurrence, I would suggests a different approach that would eliminate the looping. Add a UUID column to the main table (used to identify the new records). Then use a temp table (with an auto populating UUID column) to store the records you want to transfer. It is not as complicated as it sounds ..

(I do not have the MySQL syntax handy, so this is for SQL Server, but the overall concept is the same).

```
    -- use DEFAULT to automatically generate a UUID for each record
    CREATE TABLE #NewQuestions ( 
        , OldQuestionID int
        , TheUUIDColumn uniqueidentifier DEFAULT(NewID())
    )

    --- insert the records you want to transfer  
    INSERT INTO #NewQuestions ( OldQuestionID )
    SELECT  QuestionID
    FROM    Questions
    WHERE   .....
```

Next, use a JOIN to insert those questions back into the main table. Note, how it stores the UUID so we can identify the new records later.

```
    INSERT INTO Questions( TheUUIDColumn, Question, ... )
    SELECT  tmp.TheUUIDColumn, q.Question, ....
    FROM    Questions q INNER JOIN #NewQuestions tmp 
                 ON tmp.OldQuestionID = q.QuestionID
```

Finally, use the UUID to identify *both* the old and new id's and insert the related "answers".

```
    INSERT INTO answers ( QuestionID, Answer, ....)
    SELECT q.QuestionID, a.Answer
    FROM   Questions q 
                INNER JOIN #NewQuestions tmp ON tmp.TheUUIDColumn = q.TheUUIDColumn
                INNER JOIN answers a ON a.QuestionID = tmp.OldQuestionID
```

The temp table approach offers greater control. It is also set based, which is much more efficient than processing one record at a time via a loop.

Comment: here what it does is it is copying all the answers to a single answer if i am having another question it lefts it empty without any answers.

Comment: I think you are doing something differently than what I described. Can you update your question with the complete code that reproduces that behavior (do not overwrite the original, just append it as an update)? If it is too long to post here, use something like gist.

Comment: Yeah, there is definitely something different on your end. Here is a working example: [sql - gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6392247#file-gistfile1-sql) * [cf - gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6392229#file-gistfile1-cfm)

Comment: this is what i did https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6392579. I am having the issue is it is copying all answers to only one question though i have two questions with two answers for each question.

Comment: That would not happen unless your "answers" query only contains a single record. Perhaps `#qid#` only contains a single value. You need to use the same list of old questionID's for both the "questions" and "answers" query, like in my gist example above.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The qid contains list of old questionIDs but still it copies all answers to single. it works fine if i am having single record but raise issues when i am having more records.

Comment: (EDIT): If you run my example, it works, so there is definitely a problem with your code. What is the name of the id column in the question table - `qid`? If so there may be scoping conflict. Try using a different name to store the list of old question id's ([see my example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6392229#file-gistfile1-cfm) ). Also, while it won't cause an error - you should run both SELECT's before (and *outside*) the transaction.

Comment: Looks like some of your column/variables references are mixed up too. I marked up your gist with descriptive variables to indicate the problematic spots: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6393099

Comment: Glad I could help. If you get a chance, give the temp table approach a try. It is great for this kind of problem .. and very flexible :)

Comment: how can i use integer instead of UUID in temp table approach i want to give a try to this approach.

Comment: An integer ID would not work well here because it's not *globally* unique. So unlike w/UUID's, the temp tables in two different processes could generate the same integer ID values. Keep in mind you could always add an index on `questions.TheUUIDColumn` which should improve the performance of the JOIN's.